# Python MySql selecting from empty string

Tags: python, sql

I'm trying to select from a table so that the parameter I input can be nothing but it still will select everything

```
name = ""
mycursor.execute('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE "%%%s%%"' (name, ))
```

I was hoping to have if name is something like "", then everything in the table will be fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With LIKE it will not be possible , however you can achieve it using REGEXP

```
name = "John Doe"
regexp='^.*$'
value = (regexp if name=="" else name)
query =  "SELECT * FROM mysql.user WHERE name REGEXP '{}' ;".format(value)
print(query)
```

Note: However be wary that if you are looking for a single user, and if there are other user names that matches the string Like "John Doe1" it will return both the entries